# Dompdf not rendering INR symbol in PDF

Tags: php, dompdf, html-to-pdf

I have come across an issue with **dompdf** while trying to use INR currency symbol. I have managed to resolve the  issue using `Dejavu Sans font family`  on my local server. But, when I upload the file to a live server it just generates a `?` in place of the `INR symbol`. I have tried many methods like including providing `@fontface{...}` code ,`define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED",true)`, using 'Currencies' font family but it's not working.

```
require_once 'class-my-pdf-creator.php';
$dompdf = new my_pdf_obj();
define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->loadHtml('<style>@font-face {
  font-family: "DejaVu Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}</style><span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans; sans-serif;">&#8377;</span>');
// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->set_option('font_subsetting', true);
// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

Comment: Which version are you using for dompdf?

Comment: Am using version .6

Comment: Please check my answer, let me know if you still have issues to render INR symbol.

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage <-- Perhaps just a BTW, but this links says that 0.6.0 and older use `load_html` and `set_paper`, not `loadHtml`/`setPaper`

Comment: @teejay - Have you referred my answer? Let me know if you still facing any problems.

Comment: Thanks,but it seems I have no luck with it. It still generates a '?'.

Comment: I still have not been able to sort it out.Kindly tell me if you have any other idea to help me solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Dompdf 0.6.x and above support different encoding.

The easiest way to display the INR is to encode your document in [UTF-8](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_utf8.asp). Then you can reference the INR symbol.

Add below statement to your HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

After adding above into your HTML, you can display INR symbol with below code:

```
<span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans; sans-serif;">&#8377;</span>
```